# SUM two jquery functions in html

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have an HTML form with these two functions and I want to add the sum of both of them in a new textbox. Functions are mentioned below. How do I create the sum of both?

```
        $('.cost_p').blur(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $('.cost_p').each(function () {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
                $("#total_Material").val(sum);
            }); // here, you have your sum });​​​​​​​​​      
        });
        $('.cost_labor').blur(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $('.cost_labor').each(function () {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
                $("#total_labor").val(sum);
            }); // here, you have your sum });​​​​​​​​​      
        });
```

Comment: Do you mean: `var total = Number($("#total_Material").val()) + Number($("#total_labor").val())` ?

Comment: thanks guys i guess i wrote it wrong maybe. i know these functions work. i just need to add a function to sum both of them and display it in my html form. (#total_project). thanks

Comment: It's not clear what part you're having a problem with.  You don't need a separate function as Rohan's valid answer shows, or you can just add a function with the code from my comment - you already know how to set a value and you know how to get the values, so which part are you having difficulties with?

Comment: i am trying to add this

Comment: $('.total_cost').blur(function () {
                var sum = 0;
                $('.total_cost').each(function () {
                    sum += Number($(#total_Material).val()) + Number($(#total_labor).val());
                    $("#total_project").val(sum);
                }); // here, you have your sum });​​​​​​​​​      
            });

Comment: anyone can assist?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
$('.cost_p').blur(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.cost_p').each(function () {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });
        $("#total_Material").html(sum);   
    });
    $('.cost_labor').blur(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.cost_labor').each(function () {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });
        $("#total_labor").html(sum);    
    });
```

Comment: thanks Bloody. i know these functions work. i just another one that adds the total for both of these functions. (#total_project)  thanks

Comment: like this ?
$('#total_project').html(Number($('#total_Material').html()) + Number($('#total_labor').html()));